# Switching Git to use SSH

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have an SSH key set up and added to Git servers. Even then, while using Git from my command line, it still uses username and password for authentication. Is there are any command to change my authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for credential helpers.  Check out the git documentation here: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.9/gitcredentials.html

My guess is that `git config --global credential.helper cache` will do the trick.

If you're on a mac and installed git using homebrew you can use this: `git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain`.

There's another stack overflow question with answers that go more in depth about git credentials here: [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-on-github).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Did you set your remote branch URL using git protocol?

You can set by

> git remote set-url origin [SSH protocol URL]

SSH  protocol URL looks like git@github.com:torvalds/linux.git

Comment: Actually that is an SSH URL. A git protocol URL would begin with `git://`. See [git-fetch(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html#URLS).